# Adding up the results of two queries using a union or join

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have two mysql queries that I have combined using a union.  I get the results I want.  However, I am wondering if there is a way to combine fields that have the same name.  For example I am getting the results from the first table in the image.  What I want to do is combing the two promo fields that have the name "test" into one field and add the three columns (free, none, pay).  The results I want are in the second table.

[image]

Here is my query

```
 select users.refer as promo, 
                            count( case when plan = 'free' then 1  end ) as free,
                            count( case when plan = '' then 1 end ) as none,
                            count( case when plan <> 'free' and plan <> '' then 1 end) as pay,
                            promos.status as status
                            from users
                            inner join promos on users.refer = promos.name
                            where refer <> ''
                            group by refer
Union 
select subscriptions.promo as promo,
                            count( case when plan = 'free' then 1  end ) as free,
                            count( case when plan = '' then 1 end ) as none,
                            count( case when plan <> 'free' and plan <> '' then 1 end) as pay,
                            promos.status as status
                            from subscriptions
                            inner join promos on subscriptions.promo = promos.name
                            inner join users on subscriptions.user_id = users.id
                            where promo <> ''
                            group by promo
```

Comment: What should the final `status` value be if they're different in the two queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your query in a subquery, and then use `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT promo, SUM(free) AS free, SUM(none) AS none, SUM(pay) AS pay, MAX(status) AS status
FROM ( put your query here ) AS subquery
GROUP BY promo
```